# Drawing geometry with fixed scaling?

Tags: geometry, java, geotools

I drew the wind barbs on the map based on the coordinates data with the step of 2 degrees. But I am not satisfied with the fact that after the map reprojecting the size of the wind barbs changes. Is it possible to draw a wind barbs with exactly the same size with GeoTools?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to produce size invariant wind barbs is to make use of the `Windbarbs` mark in your style, rather than trying to construct it in map units (which is why yours change size with projection).

Based on this [blog post](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/rtx/wind_barbs.html) by GeoSolutions you can use a SLD file like this:

```
     <FeatureTypeStyle>
         <Rule>
           <PointSymbolizer>
              <Graphic>
                 <Mark>
                   <WellKnownName>windbarbs://default(
                    <ogc:PropertyName>speed</ogc:PropertyName>)[m/s]?emisphere=
                    <ogc:PropertyName>emisphere</ogc:PropertyName>
                   </WellKnownName>
                      <Stroke>
                         <CssParameter name="stroke">000000</CssParameter>
                         <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                      </Stroke>
                   </Mark>
                   <Size>
                      20
                   </Size>
                   <Rotation>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>direction</ogc:PropertyName>
                 </Rotation>
              </Graphic>
           </PointSymbolizer>
           <PointSymbolizer>
              <Graphic>
                 <Mark>
                   <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                    <Fill>
                       <CssParameter name="fill">
                          <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>
                       </CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                 </Mark>
                 <Size>3</Size>
              </Graphic>
           </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
```

This draws a wind barb based on speed, direction and hemisphere and a small dot for the location of your measurement. Modifying your code something like this:

```
// create the parser with the sld configuration
Configuration config = new SLDConfiguration();
Parser parser = new Parser(config);

// the xml instance document above
InputStream xml = new FileInputStream(new File("wind.sld"));

org.geotools.styling.Style[] styles = null;
// parse

StyleFactory styleFactory = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();
SLDParser stylereader = new SLDParser(styleFactory, xml);
styles = stylereader.readXML();
Layer wlayer = new FeatureLayer(DataUtilities.source(features), styles[0]);
map.addLayer(wlayer);
```

Where `features` is my `SimpleFeatureCollection` of random wind speeds, you can either follow that or create a `DataStore` and get a `FeatureSource` from that.

[image]

and if you reproject the map you get:

[image]

If you study the blog post you will see some options for changing the size of the marks based on zoom level. Note if you have a grid of `u` and `v` then you can use the SLD in the blog post unchanged.

I think you should be able to construct the SLD programmatically but this is left as an exercise for the interested reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ian! I will try. Thank you for your help

Comment: Do I need to install GeoServer in this case?

Comment: no, GeoTools underlies all of GeoServer - see my update

Comment: I am sorry, but I need to precise whether it is possible to get SimpleFeatureCollection from sld file or I should use SimpleFeatureCollection which I have created programatically?
And also I need to precise how can I make request http://localhost:8083/geoserver/geosolutions/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=geosolutions:windView&styles=gray&bbox=-180,-90,180,90&width=658&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/png from geotools to get windbarb images?

Comment: Is sld file use to getting only Style? Am I right or not?

Comment: The SLD contains just the style, it's easier than building it programatically in this case.

Comment: Ian, I have got exception 'Unable to find function parameter'. How should I initialize this function parameter in my code to made it been recognized? Has it relevance to filters?

Comment: there are no functions in my SLD you must have miscopied something

Comment: I use Style description from blog.post https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/rtx/wind_barbs.html. PropertyNames I have added to my SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder, but i don't know what to do with Functions ...

Comment: I have u and v wind components in database

Comment: I saw the geotools manual (http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html). For example sth like this: FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2( GeoTools.getDefaultHints() );

Set<FeatureId> fids = new HashSet<FeatureId>();
fids.add( ff.featureId("ROAD.1") );
fids.add( ff.featureId("ROAD.2") );
Filter filter = ff.id( fids );                                                                                              But I think I should get Fuction throught parsing sld file

Comment: if you have a new question please ask it as a new question, also please don't edit the code out of your question - it is important